# Memory leaks in nodejs (express.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I faced the issue of memory leaks in nodejs (express.js), I tried some tutorials on the internet but in their case, the leaky class is quite clear and not so hard to detect.
In my case, I can detect the Constructor of leaky class is Unit8Array (using chrome dev tool), but, I do not know why I have tons of them (260139 instances) and it leads to memory leaks

Thanks in advance for helping, I stuck in this for long times.

[image: Heap profiler]

Comment: can you add some code?

Comment: I cannot find which part of my code causing leaks, I am seeking for it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer for my issue, it is in the core of node when writing to many small chunks with stream (in my case is logging to file)

https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/pull/8826

I saw that it has a patch to fix this issue on node-v0.x.x but I'm using node-v0.12.4 but it is still there.
When I upgraded to node-v5.9.0, the leaks disappeared.